# Matplotlib: Axis label position with .get_window_extent()

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, position

I would like to apend a text with `ax.text()` next to the yAxis label. For that I read out the position of the label and transform it like this:

```
labelpos = ax.yaxis.label.get_window_extent()
box = labelpos.transformed(ax.transAxes.inverted())
```

To control the position i use a rectangle from `.patches` like this:

```
rect = Rectangle((box.xmin,box.ymin),box.width,box.height,
                  clip_on=False, fill=False, transform= ax.transAxes,ec='r', zorder=1000)
ax.add_patch(rect)
```

This is the result:

[image]

As you can see, the position is not always right. It looks like the ticklabel width has something to do with it. How do I compensate for that?
I've tried using `.get_ticklabel_extents`, converting it and create a rectangle:

```
extents1, extents2 = ax.yaxis.get_ticklabel_extents(renderer = fig.canvas.get_renderer())
box = extents2.transformed(ax.transAxes.inverted())
```

This is the result:

[image]

Still, the same offset remains when the tick labels getting longer. Any ideas?

---

**EDIT:**

After some research I have found my problem could lay way deeper, for the`matplotlib.artist.Artist.get_window_extent` it says [from here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.get_window_extent.html?highlight=get_window_extent#matplotlib.artist.Artist.get_window_extent):

> Be careful when using this function, the results will not update if
>   the artist window extent of the artist changes.

Soo... could it be that the labels getting moved by the artist and it is not possible to read out the current position?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to have a y axis label that is 2 lines long? So that first line would be the actual label, and whatever you want to put in the `ax.text` would be on the second line?

Comment: Do you mean with a `\n` in the string like `par.set_ylabel("this is vertical\ntest")` ? That's not an option because i need to adress the two strings separately. To change the color as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Use [complex annotation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/text/annotations.html#using-complex-coordinates-with-annotations)
With this it is possible to exactly position the annotation to the axislabel:

```
                    an1 = par.annotate("text", xy=(0, 0), xycoords=ax.yaxis.label,
                                        xytext=(0, -20), textcoords="offset points",
                                         va="center", ha="left",rotation=90)
```

Answerd here: [matplotlib Forum](https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/get-window-extent-of-axis-label-wrong/21234)